# Xamarin iOS - How to get binding with CFNetwork framework dependency to work

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin, cfnetwork

I'm working on an iOS static library binding that requires CFNetwork framework.
I've seen examples of how to DllImport the CFNetwork, but it requires that the method is extern static. 
Unfortunately this appears to be invalid on the methods in the linkwith.cs
The library seems to actually work and starts a curl command, but I get an error:

```
-[MKNetworkOperation operationFailedWithError:] [Line 1293] State: 0
```

I'm assuming this is because I haven't imported CFNetwork since the library works with a regular XCode iOS project.
Also, every time I run the project in the simulator it asks if I want to allow network connections.
This doesn't occur in a normal XCode project using the library either.

Here are all the relevant files:

ApiDefinition.cs http://pastebin.com/p3S0H28X

withlink.cs http://pastebin.com/UR0X2pZ1

Build output http://pastebin.com/aTbdW2Gj

App output http://pastebin.com/Hxcuufgj

I appreciate any help you folks can provide. 
Thanks!

[EDIT - 2015-08-26]

So I found this:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

Which unfortunately just seems to have lead me down a rabbit hole.

In our test app I put in the extra build arguments as stated in the article:

> To Configure Xamarin.iOS To Link the Library, on the project options for your final executable (not the library itself, but the final program) you need to add in iOS Build's Extra argument (these are part of your project options) the "-gcc_flags" option followed by a quoted string that contains all the extra libraries that are required for your program, for example:
>
> -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lMylibrary -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libMyLibrary.a"
>
> The above example will link libMyLibrary.a
>
> You can use the -gcc_flags to specify any set of command line
>   arguments to pass to the GCC compiler used to do the final link of
>   your executable. For example, this command line, also references the
>   CFNetwork framework:
>
> -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lMylibrary -lSystemLibrary -framework CFNetwork -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libMyLibrary.a"

I replaced -lMylibrary and libMyLibrary.a with the correct names and then I got a ton of errors stating I had duplicate entries. I imagine because I am already referencing the binding DLL. Also -lSystemLibrary was throwing errors so I removed it.

Finally I tried this:

> -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -framework CFNetwork"

And it builds without error, but I still get

> -[MKNetworkOperation operationFailedWithError:] [Line 1288]

The app's build output can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/sLNUwYwX

Still hoping someone can help!

[EDIT 2015-09-03]
I still get the MKNetworkOperation error when running in the simulators. Now that I have my iPad back I've tried to test it on that. The app crashes completely when run on the iPad with the following output:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[ApiEngine randomStringOfLength:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742a3900   at
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:167
>   at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime:throw_ns_exception (intptr)   at at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) ApiDefinition.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend
>   (intptr,intptr)   at shared2you.Shared2YouAdManager.StartDetection ()
>   [0x0001b] in :0   at
>   s2u_xamarin_uni.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication
>   application, Foundation.NSDictionary launchOptions) [0x00021] in
>   /Users/manns41078/Desktop/Xamarin
>   Projects/s2u_xamarin_uni/s2u_xamarin_uni/AppDelegate.cs:50   at at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
>   principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46
>   at s2u_xamarin_uni.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008]
>   in /Users/manns41078/Desktop/Xamarin
>   Projects/s2u_xamarin_uni/s2u_xamarin_uni/Main.cs:12

The library IS a FAT library and works in XCode no problem. Why is Xamarin giving me such heartache for a binding?? The java version was a cake walk.

Comment: Are you expecting the line just before that error: `2015-08-21 17:30:07.498 s2u_xamarin_uni[2695:66809] Shared to you status: -1 - message: STATUS_APP_NOT_FOUND_LOCAL`?

Comment: Yes, but the status message should be a success message. So that's coming through the delegate for the SDK's binding. It indicates the CURL command didn't get through.

Comment: Is the curl command correct? Does it work if you execute it from a terminal?

Comment: It should be OK. It works fine when I use the library in a regular XCode project. However, when I try that CURL command through bash it tells me that there's invalid json at column 119 for an unmatched bracket, but I see no such issue in the JSON post data.
Also I should mention that I got my iPad back to do some testing on. The app completely crashes when installed to iPad I've added the notes on it in the original post.

Comment: are you saying that you get that STATUS_APP_NOT_FOUND_LOCAL message in the Xcode project as well?

Comment: No I get the correct message that it connects to the server API. What I'm saying is that the SDK works 100% in a regular XCode project. So it's not the CURL command. It's something to do with the binding process.

Comment: What's printed when running the Xcode project? If a curl command is printed there too, it must be different it if succeeds (it may be the binding process which causes it to be different, in which case knowing the actual difference may help diagnosing this).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't print in the Xcode project since it succeeds. I'd have to modify the SDK to have it always print out and I'm trying to avoid that. Do you really think the binding process would modify the curl command? If so how would I prevent it?

Comment: additional:
In the binding project I've got the frameworks listed in the link with cs and I've put GCC flags in the actual app to link the frameworks for the SDK. It's not clear from Xamarin docs if this is right or not (I've heard both stories on the forums).

Comment: if you can modify the SDK to debug what's going on, that would certainly make things easier. Also can you post your code (in both C# and ObjC) that uses the API?

Comment: I can't share that publicly as it's proprietary and under NDA. We've decided to hire someone with experience in Xamarin. I'll report back with the findings in a week or so.